# What is an optimal data-structure for retrieving id-values recursively?

Tags: python, database, recursion

What I'm trying to do is create a `mapped id-table` that in theory looks like below nested dictionary.

```
Ids = {
    "League_id": {
        "League_name":"NAME",
        "League_abbre": "ABBREVIATION"
        "seasons_id": {         
            "label":"LABEL",
            "teams":{
                "team_id": {
                "Player_id":"PLAYER"
                            }
                    }
                }
    "League_id": {                           
        "League_name":"NAME",
        "League_abbre": "ABBREVIATION"
        "seasons_id": {         
            "label":"LABEL",
            "teams":{
                "team_id": {
                "Player_id":”PLAYER"
                            }
                    }

                }
        }
```

The problem is that each "layer" has to be merged recursively, meaning that I must get the first layer of Ids before I'm able to retrieve the second layer of Ids, thereafter merge the two layers. After merging the two layers I have to retrieve the first and second layer of Ids from the merged dict to get the third layer of Ids, and then again merge, and so forth. The different layers are the following.

```
1 layer: League_id (All are unique)
2 layer: Season_id (All are unique, seasons_ids has to be mapped to the right league_id)
3 layer:  teams_id (All are unique, teams_id has to be mapped to the right league_id, can be part of multiple seasons)
4 layel: player_id (All are unique, players_id has to be mapped to the right team_id, can be part of different team_id for different season_id)
```

So with each layer it becomes more and more difficult to to retrieve the different Ids since they can't be easily be queried in the second and third layer since I need to do nested loops.
**My question is**, what data-structure can be used so that all the Ids can be easily queried?

Below is the queries I do to retrieve the ids them self from the data-base I use:

```
  League_id: /competitions
  Season_id: /competitions/{{League_id}}
  teams_id: /teams/comps{{League_id}}/compSeasons{{Season_id}}
  player_id: /teams/{{teams_id}}/compseasons/{{Season_id}}/staff
```

When all id's have been retrieved from the data-base and mapped to their layers one should easily be able to retrieve and id be doing like below for example:

```
League_id = 1
Season_id = 274
Ids[League_id][Season_id]
```

And get all the team_ids in that season_id.

```
#Small script and different urls to view the different layers of Ids:

import json
import requests

layer1 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions' #League Ids
layer2 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions/1/compseasons'#Season Ids for League_id: 1
layer3 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams?comps=1&pageSize=100&compSeasons=274'#Teams_Ids for League_id: 1, Season_id:274
layer4 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/1/compseasons/274/staff' #Players_Ids for team_id: 1, Season_id:274
def view_raw_input(url):
    """View the input data that I use to retrieve the different Ids"""
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                        'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
              }
    params = (('pageSize', '100'),)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
    if url == 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/1/compseasons/274/staff':
        data = response
    else:
        data = response['content']
    print(data)
```

All input is appreciated, Many thanks to you that will read through all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer a more or less OO approach, but using dicts you can still do very well, consider something like this:

```
import json
import requests

layer1 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions' #League Ids
layer2 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions/1/compseasons'#Season Ids for League_id: 1
layer3 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams?comps=1&pageSize=100&compSeasons=274'#Teams_Ids for League_id: 1, Season_id:274
layer4 = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/1/compseasons/274/staff' #Players_Ids for team_id: 1, Season_id:274


def load_raw_data(url):
    """View the input data that I use to retrieve the different Ids"""
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                        'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
                        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
              }
    params = (('pageSize', '100'),)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
    except:
        return {}

    if url.endswith('staff'):
        data = response['players']
    else:
        data = response['content']
        # note: bit of a hack, for some reason 'id' is a float, but everywhere it's referenced, it's an int
        for d in data:
            d['id'] = int(d['id'])

    return data


class TeamPlayers(dict):
    _players = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def load_players_for_team(self, team, comp):
        ds = load_raw_data(
            f'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/{team}/compseasons/{comp}/staff')
        self.clear()
        for d in ds:
            self._players[d['id']] = d
            self[d['id']] = self._players[d['id']]


class SeasonTeams(dict):
    _teams = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Team(dict):
        def __init__(self, competition, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self['competition'] = competition
            self.players = TeamPlayers()

        def load_players(self):
            self.players.load_players_for_team(self['id'], self['competition'])

    def load_teams_for_season(self, season, comp):
        ds = load_raw_data(
            f'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams?comps={comp}&pageSize=100&compSeasons={season}')
        self.clear()
        for d in ds:
            d['competition'] = comp
            self._teams[d['id']] = self.Team(comp, d)
            self[d['shortName']] = self._teams[d['id']]


class Season(dict):
    all_teams = SeasonTeams()

    def __init__(self, competition, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['competition'] = competition
        self.teams = SeasonTeams()

    def load_teams(self):
        self.teams.load_teams_for_season(self['id'], self['competition'])


class League(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.seasons = {}

    def load_seasons(self):
        ds = load_raw_data(f'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions/{self["id"]}/compseasons')
        self.seasons = {d['label']: Season(self['id'], d) for d in ds}


class Football:
    def __init__(self):
        self.leagues = {}

    def load_leagues(self):
        ds = load_raw_data('https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions')
        self.leagues = {d['abbreviation']: League(d) for d in ds}


fb = Football()
fb.load_leagues()
fb.leagues['EN_PR'].load_seasons()
fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].load_teams()

# load the players for a specific team
fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].teams['Arsenal'].load_players()

# or perhaps for all
for team in fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].teams.values():
    team.load_players()

print(fb.leagues)
print(fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons)
print(fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].teams)
print(fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].teams['Arsenal'].players)

print('goalies:',
      [player['name']['display']
       for team in fb.leagues['EN_PR'].seasons['2019/20'].teams.values()
       for player in team.players.values() if 'position' in player['info'] and player['info']['position'] == 'G'])
```

It avoids loading teams or players twice and only loads what you need. But of course, deciding what you need may still be tricky. You could make this fancier by having the various classes load their contents on demand.

I wanted to share the output as well, but the size exceeds what StackOverflow will allow me to post, so please run yourself. If it seems a bit slow, that's mainly because it's loading all players for all teams in a single season of the Premier League - you could be a bit more frugal, depending on what you want to do. I figured it'd be fun to list all the goalies for that season.

Comment: Wow this is beautiful, one small remark I seem has by-past during my excitement is is that a `layers_link` can contain multiple pages and that one has to do a `while loop` and and add `('"page", str(page))` while counting up the pages and break `if page == response["pageInfo"]["numPages"]:
                break`

Comment: Put will look at this masterpiece while my terminal is getting blown, thank you so much for taking your time @Grismar to write ALL of this up!

Comment: Ok, well that'd just be a bit of extra code on the `load_raw_data` - I do like how the final lines make it very clear what is being accessed and you only load the data you actually need, let me know if the solution raises further questions.

Comment: Also note that, although teams play in seasons, the API doesn't always return data for the players in those teams, hence the ugly `try .. except ..` - you'd want to deal with that a bit more gracefully.

Comment: This is really clean, I have tried implementing an OO myself, but have only created one class with methods that return the different `layers`, but this, this is really clean!

Comment: This is so impressive!!

Comment: Once again, this is the absolute maddest thing I've seen, I've struggled for weeks trying to find a fitting structure, and you delivered a complete run-down in less than 2h.

Comment: Only took that long because I first got a haircut after posting my comments - don't be discouraged though, I've been programming for 30 years, that helps ;-). Good luck with you further coding, you're welcome. And thanks for asking such a clean question and responding well to queries, good SO stuff.

Comment: Not discouraged at all, been learning python for about a year on my spear time, this only encourages my more! The pleasure is all mine, I should be thanking! The reason for why I believe the question is perceived as clean is because I’ve been writing docs for about a week! Thank you for this experience, very glad for the encounter and encouragement!

Comment: I've spent quite some time trying to understand your code and thing that I can't get into my head is how you can do `self["id"]` in `class League` since `id` is contained within `self.leagues.values()`. I understand that `class League` inherits from `class Football`, but I can't understand why just doing `self["id"]` works? Again, thank you for your previous answers!

Comment: In `League`, `self` refers to the league, which is a dictionary, loaded from the API, which has a field name `id`. `self.leagues` (where `self` is an instance of `Football`) does contain all the `League`s and those do contain their individual `id`s - remember that `self` always refers to the instance of the class it is in for which it was called. `League` does not inherit from `Football`, it inherits from `dict` and it gets instantiated with `self.leagues = {d['abbreviation']: League(d) for d in ds}`, so each `dict` `d` (that has an `id` already) gets turned into a `League`, giving it an `id`.

Comment: This stuff is hard though and with the number of classes and the variation in how they are implemented here, it's not an easy example to start with. Take the time to truly understand it and feel free to ask more, or send me a message away from this thread, if it gets too detailed.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to create handler functions to return the correct dictionary structure for each level. You can simply chain these handlers together to built the structure:

```
import requests
def get_data(url):
   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
                    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
          }
   params = (('pageSize', '100'),)
   return requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()

links = ['https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions', 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/competitions/{}/compseasons', 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams?comps={}&pageSize=100&compSeasons={}', 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/{}/compseasons/{}/staff']

def l4(link, *args):
   print(link.format(*args))
   try:
      return {i['playerId']:i for i in get_data(link.format(*args))['players'] if i}
   except:
      return {}

def l3(link, *args):
   return {int(i['club']['id']):l4(links[3], int(i['club']['id']), int(args[-1])) for i in get_data(link.format(*args))['content'] if i}

def l2(link, *args):
   return {int(i['id']):{'label':i['label'], 'teams':l3(links[2], *args, int(i['id']))} for i in get_data(link.format(*args))['content'] if i}

def l1(link, *args):
   return {int(i['id']):{"League_name":i['description'], "League_abbre":i['abbreviation'], **l2(links[1], int(i['id']))} for i in get_data(link.format(*args))['content'] if i}


result = l1(links[0])
```

Comment: Wow, this is a completely different approach then what I have tried. I'm currently trying to wrap my head around the dict comprehensions, and see what it outputs. Thank you for taking your time to provide this!

Comment: @MisterButter No problem! Please see my recent edit, as there was a `null` value being produced by one of the player ID api routes. I added a check to filter a null response out.

Comment: I was just about to comment on that. I believe I would unfortunately have to dumb your elegant code down so to make it robust to null values or empty dicts. I'm currently running your recent edited code, eagerly waiting for the output!!

Comment: Getting `JSONDecodeError` which I presume is because of `null` values being produced.

Comment: Yes, I think that is probably the case.... I am still waiting for my second test run to complete. Can you tell me from the error message in what function the `JSONDecodeError` was produced?

Comment: When looking through the tracebacks, I believe it's still the players route that is messy. i know for a fact that a lot of players in the API doesn't have Ids (retired etc). I know all league_ids exist and all season_ids exist, and believe all team_ids exist, but not all player_ids exist

Comment: Should maybe try using a try, except in `l4` handler

Comment: @MisterButter yes, I just hit that problem as well when I ran it again. Since it is a decode error it means there is a problem with what is being returned by the server. I suggest putting `print(link.format(*args))` call in `l4` to see what URL is causing this issue.

Comment: I will try again with that print call as well.

Comment: It seems like it's just one request, that is neglectable, just need an if statement to filter it out, it's `https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/teams/421/compseasons/288/staff`

Comment: @MisterButter The other possibility is a `try...except` in `l4`. That way you do not need to keep a running list of all failed URLs. Please see my recent edit, as I added this functionality.

Comment: if believe adding this to `l4` should do the trick, currently trying  `if get_data(link.format(*args)) != 404:`

Comment: Again, can't thank you enough for putting down this much time to this, you truly are talented coming up with this, so exited to see the output!

Comment: @MisterButter No problem, glad to help! Please let me know if you have any questions or need any help in the future.

Comment: thank you so much for offering the help, if you ever interested in forking the project, let me know! (There is so much more to this!)

Comment: Just as a funny comment, I'm bit mad at myself that I chose not to save the output done to a json, just realised that the runtime on this could be >15min! I believe it's about 8K requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208412/discussion-between-misterbutter-and-ajax1234).